# PCT application: published vs. granted

Tags: pct

I am tracking a PCT patent application on patentscope.wipo.int. Under the 'National Phase' tab, the 'National Status' is published and granted in Country #1, but only published in Country #2.
Does this mean that the patent is granted in Country #1, but in Country #2 only the patent application is published but the patent itself is not granted?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don’t link to the specific document?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really qualified to answer, but my understanding is that patents are granted country by country. It is not unlikely that a PCT will be granted is some countries and not others. Something as simple as not providing a translation can keep a patent from being issued in a specific country.

Comment: And each country has its own criteria/laws/ procedural hurdles.

Comment: I wonder how common it is for Country #1 to grant a patent, but Country #2 denies it.